# Legacy Cytoscape Attributes Format not importing

Tags: cytoscape

Reading the documentation, section 8.2 here: http://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Node_and_Edge_Column_Data.html

The docs state that the legacy attributes format is still supported in cytoscape 3.8. I have a legacy attribute file in the following format:

```
LinkerHeats
PKC = 0.05283780217268941
CDKN1B = 0.9230103703466229
RAS = 0.001407567832956147
BRCA1 = 0.0005058090659030887
```

However when I try to import the file using `File -> Import -> Table from file...` I cannot find a way for cytoscape to recognize anything but a single column, and it throws an error:

```
Table must have more than one column. Please check the selected delimeters and columns.
```

The import dialog is shown:

[image]

I can manually convert the file to CSV and import it, but it's a bit annoying to need the conversion utility since the docs suggest this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but I was able to import that file by deleting the first line of the file (e.g. the column label) and using "=" as the delimiter.  Obviously you have to rename the column before the import, but I was able to get it to work without having to convert it.  The documentation is clearly wrong and we'll make sure to remove that comment as I think we removed support for that format several releases ago when we cleaned up our File menu.

-- scooter